# sparklyr change all column names spark dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, dplyr, sparklyr

I intended to change all column names. The current rename or select operation is too labouring. I dont know if anybody has a better solution. Examples as belwo:

```
df <- data.frame(oldname1 = LETTERS, oldname2 = 1,...oldname200 = "APPLE")
df_tbl <- copy_to(sc,df,"df")
newnamelist <- paste("Name", 1:200, sep ="_")
```

How do I assign newnamelist as the new colnames? I probably cant do this:

```
df_new <- df_tbl %>% dplyr::select(Name_1 = oldname1, Name_2 = oldname2,....)
```

Comment: Does this help? `names(df)[1:3] <- sprintf("NEW_COLUMN%d", 1:3)`

You can add 'n' number of columns by changing the number in above statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `select_` with `.dots`:

```
df <- copy_to(sc, iris)

newnames <- paste("Name", 1:5, sep="_")

df %>% select_(.dots=setNames(colnames(df), newnames))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]
# Database: spark_connection
   Name_1 Name_2 Name_3 Name_4 Name_5
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <chr>
 1    5.1    3.5    1.4    0.2 setosa
 2    4.9    3.0    1.4    0.2 setosa
 3    4.7    3.2    1.3    0.2 setosa
 4    4.6    3.1    1.5    0.2 setosa
 5    5.0    3.6    1.4    0.2 setosa
 6    5.4    3.9    1.7    0.4 setosa
 7    4.6    3.4    1.4    0.3 setosa
 8    5.0    3.4    1.5    0.2 setosa
 9    4.4    2.9    1.4    0.2 setosa
10    4.9    3.1    1.5    0.1 setosa
```

You can also `select` with `!!!`:

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

df %>% select(!!! setNames(map(colnames(df), parse_quosure), newnames))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]
# Database: spark_connection
   Name_1 Name_2 Name_3 Name_4 Name_5
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <chr>
 1    5.1    3.5    1.4    0.2 setosa
 2    4.9    3.0    1.4    0.2 setosa
 3    4.7    3.2    1.3    0.2 setosa
 4    4.6    3.1    1.5    0.2 setosa
 5    5.0    3.6    1.4    0.2 setosa
 6    5.4    3.9    1.7    0.4 setosa
 7    4.6    3.4    1.4    0.3 setosa
 8    5.0    3.4    1.5    0.2 setosa
 9    4.4    2.9    1.4    0.2 setosa
10    4.9    3.1    1.5    0.1 setosa
# ... with more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions listed above did not work for me. I did find a straight forward solution documented in github which works with sparklyr.

[rename() doesn't support unquoting of character vectors #3030](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3030#issuecomment-373871506)

Below is an excerpt of my script expanding on the method described in the link above.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Generate list of column names without special characters (replace spaces and dashes with underscores)
list_new_names = colnames(spark_df) %>% str_remove_all('LAST ') %>% str_replace_all(' - ', '_') %>% str_replace_all(' ', '_')
# Generate list used to rename columns
list_new_names = colnames(spark_df) %>% setNames(list_new_names)
# Rename columns
spark_df = spark_df %>% rename(!!! list_new_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too, This worked fine for me.

```
df <- copy_to(sc, iris)
newnames <- paste("Name", 1:5, sep="_")

colnames(df) <- newnames
```